# prototypes, objects, constructors, "this", functions

Tags: javascript, function, object, constructor

How do

- prototypes
- objects
- constructors
- "this"
- functions

work in JS in relation to each other (and what exactly are they; is a constructor a function, object, prototype, "this")?

Can someone please clarify this? I have an idea of what each of them are and how they work, but not a clear one.

I think it would be easier to understand questions that arise, like, for example: "Is `a.constructor` the same as `a.prototype.constructor`", if one knows what these things are.

Comment: Did you even try "javascript object constructor" in Google?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Object - A collection of name-value pairs, for example:

```
var someObject = {
    aName: "aValue",
    name2: "value2"
}
```

Constructor - a function that 'creates' an object, for example:

```
function someObject(someParam) {
    this.someParam = someParam;
    this.getSomeParam = function() {
         return this.someParam;
    }
}
```

Prototype - a special type of object, from which other objects inherit properties. Every object has a prototype. You can use them to add a method to all instances of an object, for example:

```
String.prototype.doSomething = function() {
    //Do something with a String
}
```

Now that you have defined a `doSomething` method on the `String` prototype, all `String` objects can use it:

```
var myString = "Hello";
myString.doSomething();
```

For more information about the JavaScript language and how it works, I suggest you take a look at the [ECMAScript spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm), or for something a bit lighter, read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/a_re-introduction_to_javascript).

Comment: Thanks, especially for the links. I think I understand now.